# Run threads in each core in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, multiprocessing

I'm working with a Delphi application and I have created two threads to sync with different databases, one to read and other to write. I would like to know if Delphi is actually using all potential of each core (running on an i5 with 4 cores for example) or if I need to write a specific code to distribute the threads to each core.

I have no idea how to find this.

Comment: You should not worry about that. Let the scheduler determine what core your thread will run, remember you don't have only your process running on a machine.

Comment: It depends on what else is running on the machine. You should, as a rule, let the scheduler decide where to run the tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to do. The OS will choose the best place to run each of your threads taking into account a large number of factors completely beyond your control. The OS manages your threads in conjunction with all other threads in all other processes on the system.

Don't forget that if your threads aren't particularly busy, there will be absolutely no need to run them on different cores.

Sometimes moving code to a separate core can introduce unexpected inefficiencies. Remember CPU's have high speed memory caches; and if certain data is not available in the cache of one core, moving to it could incur *relatively slower* RAM access.

*The point I'm trying to make here, is that you trying to second-guess all these scenarios and permutations is premature optimisation. Rather let the OS do the work for you.* **You have other things you should rather focus on as indicated below.**

---

However, that said any interaction between your threads can significantly affect the OS's ability to run them on separate cores. E.g.

- At one extreme: if each of your threads do a lot of work through a shared lock (perhaps the reader thread places data in a shared location that the writer consumes, so a lock is used to avoid race conditions), then it's likely that both threads will run on the same core.
- The best case scenario would be when there is zero interaction between the threads. In this case the OS can easily run the threads on separate cores.

> *One thing to be aware of is that the threads **can interact** even if you didn't explicitly code anything to do so. The default memory manger is shared between all threads. So if you do a lot of dynamic memory allocation in each thread, you can experience contention limiting scalability across large numbers of cores.*

***So the important thing for you to focus on is getting your design "correct":***

- Ensure a "clean" separation of concerns.
- Eliminate unnecessary interaction between threads.
- Ensure whatever interaction is needed uses the most appropriate technique ***for your requirements***.

Get the above right, and the OS will schedule your threads as efficiently as it can.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing you need to do. The operating system schedules ready-to-run threads on available cores.

Comment: @acca90 Right. That's the scheduler's job.